# How to write dconf overrides for site-custom keybindings?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, mate-desktop, dconf

I want to add custom keybindings using dconf. Previously, I had do the same job using gconf and succeeded. However, there are some problems using dconf.

(I'm working on a Debian package, so file-based overrides is very easy to be packaged.)

Here is what I have:

```
# cat /etc/dconf/profile/user:
user-db:user
system-db:site

# cat /etc/dconf/db/site.d/keybindings
[org/mate/desktop/keybindings/emacs]
action='emacs'
binding='<Mod4>e'
name='Emacs'

[org/mate/desktop/keybindings/pluma]
action='pluma'
binding='<Mod4>g'
name='Text Editor'

[org/mate/desktop/keybindings/virtualbox]
action='virtualbox'
binding='<Mod4>v'
name='Virtual Box'

[org/mate/desktop/keybindings/rhythmbox]
action='rhythmbox'
binding='<Mod4>r'
name='Music Player'

# sudo dconf update
```

As you see, file `/etc/dconf/db/site.d/keybindings` contains 4 keybindings, however, only the first work, ie., <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for Emacs. Other keybindings won't work.

I can re-order the entries so that `pluma` be the first, or `virtualbox` be the first, but, the same problem again: only the first entry work. Ie., <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for pluma, or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for virtualbox. However, I can't have all these keybindings at the same time!

But wait a minute... If I move `/etc/dconf/db/site.d/keybindings` to `$HOME/.config/dconf/user.d/keybindings`, and run:

```
# cd ~/.config/dconf
# mkdir user.d
# mv /etc/dconf/db/site.d/keybindings user.d/keybindings
# sudo dconf update .
```

then everything work! Well, because I'm writing the Debian package, I can't install files to the user's homedir, so still face the problem.